# How to mock Entity Framework 6 Async methods?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I am new in mocking. I want to mock up my base repository which is depend on Entity Framework 6 DbContext But I fail. I searched in Google a lot but did not get any sufficient result. At last I got an example at [testing with async queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429#async) and try to follow but it is worked for me.

Here is my code :

DbContext :

```
public class TimeSketchContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<EmployeeSkill> EmployeeSkill { get; set; }
}
```

Base Repository :

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class, IEntity, new()
{
    protected readonly DbContext InnerDbContext;
    protected DbSet<T> InnerDbSet;

    public BaseRepository(DbContext innerDbContext)
    {
        InnerDbContext = innerDbContext;
        InnerDbSet = InnerDbContext.Set<T>();
    }

    public virtual Task<T> FindAsync(long id)
    {
        return InnerDbSet.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=>x.Id == id);
    }
```

}

Test :

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task DbTest()
    {
        var dummyData = GetEmployeeSkills();
        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<EmployeeSkill>>();

        mockSet.As<IDbAsyncEnumerable<EmployeeSkill>>()
            .Setup(x => x.GetAsyncEnumerator())
            .Returns(new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<EmployeeSkill>(dummyData.GetEnumerator()));

        mockSet.As<IQueryable<EmployeeSkill>>()
            .Setup(x => x.Provider)
            .Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<EmployeeSkill>(dummyData.Provider));

        mockSet.As<IQueryable<EmployeeSkill>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(dummyData.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<EmployeeSkill>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(dummyData.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<EmployeeSkill>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(dummyData.GetEnumerator());

        var mockContext = new Mock<TimeSketchContext>();
        mockContext.Setup(c => c.EmployeeSkill).Returns(mockSet.Object);

        var baseRepository = new BaseRepository<EmployeeSkill>(mockContext.Object);

        var data = await baseRepository.FindAsync(1);

        Assert.NotEqual(null, data);

    }

    private EmployeeSkill GetEmployeeSkill()
    {
        return new EmployeeSkill
        {
            SkillDescription = "SkillDescription",
            SkillName = "SkillName",
            Id = 1
        };
    }

    private IQueryable<EmployeeSkill> GetEmployeeSkills()
    {
        return new List<EmployeeSkill>
        {
            GetEmployeeSkill(),
            GetEmployeeSkill(),
            GetEmployeeSkill(),
        }.AsQueryable();
    }
```

Result is :

> Assert.NotEqual() Failure

I think problem is

```
 public BaseRepository(DbContext innerDbContext)
 {
     InnerDbContext = innerDbContext;
     InnerDbSet = InnerDbContext.Set<T>();  <<<<<<<<<<<
 }
```

But don`t understand why and how to solve this.

I am using :

- Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate
- Moq
- xUnit

Thank`s in advance.

Comment: For future readers: If you are injecting, say, a DbContext everywhere and you cannot abstract it to a repository/interface and you absolutely need to "mock" it, being non-virtual and all, you can use Microsoft Fakes Assemblies to accomplish this, as it does some fancy IL stuff to let you provide an alternative implementation to even a non-virtual method on an object.

Comment: I strongly recommend checking out "Effort" (https://effort.codeplex.com/), an EF unit testing tool, which creates a real-enough EF database in-memory to test against. We went through a lot of headaches with mocking EF as well, but at the end of the day, testing EF mocks is an apples-to-oranges fiasco. (For one example, mock tests use L2O rather than L2E.)

Comment: its looks a nice tool, Will check Later. whatever thanks @RJB

Comment: For EF 6, I found the code in this article very useful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429.aspx

I also ran into issues with mocking AsNoTracking(), and this brilliant answer solved the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27087604/3507333

Comment: That effort url comes up with a Google warning about dangerous programs ahead and advises not to continue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are right the problem is in your `InnerDbContext.Set<T>();` statement.

In the current version of the EF (6.0.2) the [`DbContext.Set<T>` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679544%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) is **not** `virtual` so it cannot be mocked with Moq.

So you cannot easily make your test pass except by changing your design of the `BaseRepository` to not depend on the whole `DbContext` but on one `DbSet<T>`:

So something like:

```
public BaseRepository(DbSet<T> dbSet)
{
    InnerDbSet = dbSet;
}
```

Then you can pass directly in your mocked DbSet.

Or you can create a wrapper interface for `DbContext`:

```
public interface IDbContext
{
    DbSet<T> Set<T>() where T : class;
}

public class TimeSketchContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<EmployeeSkill> EmployeeSkill { get; set; }
}
```

Then use `IDbContext` in your `BaseRepository`:

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class, IEntity, new()
{
    protected readonly IDbContext InnerDbContext;
    protected DbSet<T> InnerDbSet;

    public BaseRepository(IDbContext innerDbContext)
    {
        InnerDbContext = innerDbContext;
        InnerDbSet = InnerDbContext.Set<T>();
    }

    public virtual Task<T> FindAsync(long id)
    {
        return InnerDbSet.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}
```

And finally you just need to change two lines in your test to make it pass:

```
var mockContext = new Mock<IDbContext>();
mockContext.Setup(c => c.Set<EmployeeSkill>()).Returns(mockSet.Object);
```

Comment: Downvoting because the method is `FindAsync`, but the implementation is of `FirstAndDefaultAsync`.