# Mock DbContext.set<T>.Add() EF6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I have the following classes (where PilsnerContext is a DbContext class):

```
public abstract class ServiceBase<T> : IService<T> where T: class, IEntity
{
    protected readonly PilsnerContext Context;

    protected ServiceBase(PilsnerContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public virtual T Add(T entity)
    {
        var newEntity = Context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        Context.SaveChanges();
        return newEntity;
    }
}

public class ProspectsService : ServiceBase<Prospect>
{
    public ProspectsService(PilsnerContext context) : base(context){}

}
```

And i'm trying to make a unit test of the Add method mocking the context like:

```
[TestClass]
public class ProspectTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void AddProspect()
    {
        var mockProspect = new Mock<DbSet<Prospect>>();
        var mockContext = new Mock<PilsnerContext>();

        mockContext.Setup(m => m.Prospects).Returns(mockProspect.Object);

        var prospectService = new ProspectsService(mockContext.Object);

        var newProspect = new Prospect()
        {
            CreatedOn = DateTimeOffset.Now,
            Browser = "IE",
            Number = "1234567890",
            Visits = 0,
            LastVisitedOn = DateTimeOffset.Now
        };

        prospectService.Add(newProspect);

        mockProspect.Verify(m=>m.Add(It.IsAny<Prospect>()), Times.Once);
        mockContext.Verify(m=>m.SaveChanges(), Times.Once);
    }
}
```

But the assert:

```
mockProspect.Verify(m=>m.Add(It.IsAny<Prospect>()), Times.Once);
```

Is failing, I assume is because I'm using Context.set().Add() instead of Context.Prospects.Add() in the Add method but how is the correct way to pass this test?

The exception is:

```
Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: m => m.Add(It.IsAny<Prospect>()) No setups configured. No invocations performed.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for a well-written first question, welcome to SO!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mock Entity Framework 6 Async methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062745/how-to-mock-entity-framework-6-async-methods)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried your solution Patrick Quirk but I was getting an error telling me that DbContext.Set is not virtual.

I found the solution for that here:

[How to mock Entity Framework 6 Async methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062745/how-to-mock-entity-framework-6-async-methods)

Creating an interface of the DbContext like

```
    public interface IPilsnerContext
   {
       DbSet<T> Set<T>() where T : class;
   }
```

That way I could mock it.

Thanks!

This is my first question btw, I'm not sure if I can mark this question as duplicated or something.

Comment: That question is pretty close, I'll flag your question as a possible duplicate.  Yours is a subset of the question you link to, so I think that qualifies.

Answer (score 22):

It looks like you're just missing the setup to return your `DbSet`:

```
mockContext.Setup(m => m.Set<Prospect>()).Returns(mockProspect.Object);
```

Comment: `DbSet.Set()` is a non virtual method.

Comment: [The docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696521%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) say it is, unless I'm looking at the wrong method.  I'm not an EF user, so I could be completely wrong.

Comment: Apparently the method was made virtual in [this commit](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/6dc8879b13f54382eb087dd010636bebc15fdc69), which is in EF 6.1.0 and later.  Just making sure I'm not crazy!

Comment: most example on msdn is with service and direcly using context; Without this line, generic repository cannot test! Thanks...

Comment: In my opinion this should be the answer to the question