# Mock AsNoTracking Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking, moq

How do I mock AsNoTracking method? 
In below example, DbContext has injected to the service class.It works fine if I remove AsNoTracking extension method from GetOrderedProducts method, but with AsNoTracking test fails because it returns null. 
I've also tried to mock AsNoTracking to return proper value but it didn't work.

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
    int SaveAllChanges();
}

public class Entites : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }  // This is virtual because Moq needs to override the behaviour

    public new virtual IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class   // This is virtual because Moq needs to override the behaviour 
    {
        return base.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public int SaveAllChanges()
    {
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}

    public class ProductService
{
    private readonly IDbSet<Product> _products;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;

    public ProductService(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
        _products = _uow.Set<Product>();
    }
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetOrderedProducts()
    {
        return _products.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
    }
}

    [TestFixture]
public class ProductServiceTest
{
    private readonly ProductService _productService;

    public ProductServiceTest()
    {
        IQueryable<Product> data = GetRoadNetworks().AsQueryable();
        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Product>>();
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Product>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Product>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Product>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Product>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());
        var context = new Mock<Entites>();
        context.Setup(c => c.Products).Returns(mockSet.Object);
        context.Setup(m => m.Set<Product>()).Returns(mockSet.Object);
        context.Setup(c => c.Products.AsNoTracking()).Returns(mockSet.Object);
        _productService = new ProductService(context.Object);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Product> GetRoadNetworks()
    {
        return new List<Product>
        {
            new Product
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "A"
            },
            new Product
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "B"
            },
            new Product
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "C"
            }
        };
    }

    [Test]
    public void GetOrderedProductTest()
    {
        IEnumerable<Product> products = _productService.GetOrderedProducts();
        List<string> names = products.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
        var expected = new List<string> {"A", "B", "C"};
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(names, expected);
    }
}
```

The problem is AsNoTracking returns null in unit test
[image]

Comment: The remarks suggest something other than null should be returned: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

Comment: @ta.speot.is That's right, but it returns null.

Comment: I've aleady answered the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72687854/16050768).

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/QueryableExtensions.cs#L623) of the `AsNoTracking()` extension method:

```
public static IQueryable AsNoTracking(this IQueryable source)
{
    var asDbQuery = source as DbQuery;
    return asDbQuery != null ? asDbQuery.AsNoTracking() : CommonAsNoTracking(source);
}
```

Since `source` (your `DbSet<Product>` you're trying to mock) is indeed a `DbQuery` (because `DbSet` is deriving from `DbQuery`), it tries to invoke the 'real' (non-mocked) `AsNoTracking()` method which rightfully returns null.

Try to mock the `AsNoTracking()` method as well:

```
mockSet.Setup(x => x.AsNoTracking()).Returns(mockSet.Object);
```

Comment: This is not working on dotnet/EF core: Expression references a method that does not belong to the mocked object: x => x.AsNoTracking<Tags>(). I guess because AsNoTracking() is not on IQueryable anymore but instead on 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions'? Any idea about a solution?

Comment: @Bassebus, I'm not familiar enough with EF core to answer the question but it might deserve a new question

Comment: okay, thanks. I did some more googling and think this might be the problem/solution https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7937

Comment: So what did you use as the final solution?

Comment: For EF Core, please try my library [here](https://github.com/huysentruitw/entity-framework-core-mock). I've also created an EF6 version [here](https://github.com/huysentruitw/entity-framework-mock).

Comment: What is the type of mockSet here?

Comment: @Triynko, According to the original code by the OP, it's `Mock<DbSet<Product>>` (using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/)

Answer (score 6):

You have:

```
context.Setup(c => c.Products).Returns(mockSet.Object);
context.Setup(m => m.Set<Product>()).Returns(mockSet.Object);
context.Setup(c => c.Products.AsNoTracking()).Returns(mockSet.Object);
```

But remember that extension methods are just syntactic sugar. So:

```
c.Products.AsNoTracking()
```

is really just:

```
System.Data.Entity.DbExtensions.AsNoTracking(c.Products)
```

therefore your mock setup above is meaningless.

The question is what the static [`DbExtensions.AsNoTracking(source)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352.aspx) actually does to its argument. Also see [the thread *What difference does .AsNoTracking() make?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211680/)

What happens if you just remove the `Setup` involving `AsNoTracking` from your test class?

It might be helpful to give all your mocks `MockBehavior.Strict`. In that case you will discover if the members the static method invokes on them, are mockable by Moq (i.e. virtual methods/properties in a general sense).
Maybe you can mock the non-static [method `DbQuery.AsNoTracking`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbquery.asnotracking.aspx) if necessary.

Comment: Thank you, I need to use AsNoTracking in order to improve performance of the query.

I am looking for a way to fix this null exception problem when I use AsNoTracking in service classes.

Comment: In my EF (version 6.0) it is not always an extension method but a virtual method defined in `DbQuery<>`. Only when you refer to your data as `IQueryable<>` then you'll have to use the extension method.

Comment: @haim770 You are absolutely right. Your answer is much more precise than mine was, although I did hint at the non-static method on `DbQuery<>` in the last sentence. I will repeat that if he had used `Strict` mocks he would have got an exception telling him what method he needed to mock, instead of just waiting until the `NullReferenceException` arose. People use loose mocks too much.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, Thanks. I don't know much about strict vs. loose mocking. But out of curiosity, had he used strict mocks when exactly can we except the exception to be thrown?

Comment: @haim770 With a strict mock, as soon as some member that was not `Setup`, is called, an exception is thrown saying "all invocations must have a corresponding setup". So if type `T` has a method `int Meth()`, and `Meth` is virtual enough that Moq can control its implementation, then an example is: `var m = new Mock<T>(MockBehavior.Strict); /* no setup for Meth */ m.Object.Meth(); /* throws an exception */` In contrast with a loose mock, this will simply return `default(int)`, or `0`. (In the scenario of the question it returned `default(DbQuery)`, or `null`.)

Answer (score -2):

you can use **Entity Framework Effort** to mock the AsNoTracking(), also you can mock the Db Transactions and Entity State by using Effort - [Official site for Effort](https://entityframework-effort.net/)

Comment: Link only answer is not useful.  Consider removing to save the universe time from reading this again.